# How can I show month and year in 12's timezone in swift?

Tags: swift

```
func getMonYearDateFormat() -> String {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()//EEEE, d, MMM
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = is24Hour() ? "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss" : "yyyy-MM-dd' 'h:mm:ss a"
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
            guard let oldDate = dateFormatter.date(from: self) else { return "" }
            let convertDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            convertDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
            
            return convertDateFormatter.string(from: oldDate)
        }
```

*I show month and year as title in table view. I wrote this function to convert the date of the relevant card to month and year. If the device is in the 24-hour time zone, the function works properly. However, if the device is in the 12th time zone, it returns blank and I cannot see the month and year of the relevant card. I couldn't find the part that I wrote incorrectly in the function.*

Comment: Even if I delete the time, the part I mentioned in the 12 time zone returns empty.

Comment: If the user is in 12 slices on the device, for example, the date of the card does not appear as 24 October, and it returns blank. If the user is in the 24th time zone, it appears as October 24th.

Comment: That's why I add control for selections 24 and 12.                                                   func is24Hour() -> Bool {
     let dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "j", options: 0, locale: Locale.current)
     return dateFormat?.firstIndex(of: "a") == nil
}

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code with 12 hour format and it works. The only thing I've. change is to use the 12 hour format without call is24Hour() because you did not provide that code. So I suspect the point of failure is the is24Hour() function.

Comment: But when I write the function in this way, a lot of data starts to come. The code that works correctly in the 24 time zone breaks down in the 12 time zone.

Comment: That's not what I mean. You need to check your function is24Hour(). I don't think it's working correctly. So if the function is unable to mark the 12 hour format, every time the function runs, it will use the 24 hour format and the conversion to date will fail for all the 12 hour formatted date.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments I would recommend you to investigate how you get this string and if possibly use the original Date object instead if it exists but below is a solution that I think handles the 12 vs 24h issue in an efficient way.

The logic is to first convert using 24h and if that returns nil then convert using the 12h format.

I have declared all formatters I use as static properties so they only get created one since creating a DateFormatter is expensive

```
extension String {
    private static let formatter24: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
    private static let formatter12: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'h:mm:ss a"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
    private static let formatterMonthYear: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
        return dateFormatter
    }()

    func getMonYearDateFormat() -> String {
        let date = Self.formatter24.date(from: self) ?? Self.formatter12.date(from: self)
        guard let date else { return "" }

        return Self.formatterMonthYear.string(from: date)
    }
}
```